# Configure the abstract at a chapter of thesis in the same page with chapter's title and contents

Tags: pdftex, thesis, abstract

I would like to produce the abstract with the following appearance.

[image]

For details, I need the abstract with this kind of top and bottom rules.

Could someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you tell us which documentclass you use?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you tell us more about the class you are using. Best would be to have a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a new environment `chapterapstract` for this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mwe}

\newenvironment{chapterabstract}{%
  \par\nobreak\noindent
  \textbf{\textit{Abstract}\hrulefill}\par\nobreak
  \small
  \noindent\ignorespaces
}{%
  \par\nobreak\normalsize
  \vskip-\ht\strutbox\noindent
  \textbf{\hrulefill}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Example Chapter}
\begin{chapterabstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{chapterabstract}
\section{Example Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: This very simple definition does only work with one column and does not prevent for unwanted page breaks.

Comment: Sorry, could your correct the typo in the line "\par\nobreal\noindent" into "\par\nobreak\noindent"? Thanks.

Comment: @VuongTrinh: Done.